# Unusual 403 behaviour on Spring MVC / Tomcat with many simultaneous requests

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, tomcat7, http-status-code-403

I have a Spring 4.2.3 MVC application with Hibernate, Jackson, and a long list of other libraries that is exhibiting strange behaviour on one server only, with four or five other near-identical servers behaving normally. The application runs in Tomcat 7 on Java 8.

A `@RestController` controller uses `@PreAuthorize` to authorize each request to an endpoint. When a user is missing the required permission that request returns a 403 (Forbidden) response, invalidates the session, and all following requests return a 401 (Unauthorized) until that user authenticates again.

The problem server spontaneously returns 403s when the user has all required permissions. Our permission evaluator logs when a user is missing a permission and in this case it doesn't log anything (including no exceptions). The server returns multiple 403 responses, not just one followed by 401s. Additionally the 403 response is the default Apache / Tomcat output whereas we have Spring configured to return a basic HTML page with its 403 for legacy scenarios where the user will see it. All this makes me think that the issue exists outside of the Spring application, perhaps in Tomcat.

In certain situations the client can send a large number of HTTP requests to the same endpoint - up to 42. I have seen the first 30 or so return 200 OK and the following 12 all return 403. The only way I've been able to suppress the spontaneous 403s is to consolidate the 42 into four HTTP requests. This consolidation is a good thing regardless of the problem, but I'd like to understand the mechanism at work here. If I don't know the limit of how many requests the server can handle then I'll never be able to trust it.

My thoughts so far are:

1. some built-in DOS protection decides that I have too many simultaneous requests and responds in the least resource-intensive way
2. Tomcat hits a thread limit and reacts in an undesirable way

What could be causing this behaviour on one server out of several?

Comment: Can you see the 403 request in your logs? And information there?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I see an error logged by the application with the HTML of the Apache 403 response dumped after it but nothing else. Our application has a default 403 response and this isn't it, so I assumed that the issue was occurring before any application code was executed, but the fact that our application logs the error suggests otherwise.

Comment: Error page being different is ok as web servers intercept and show their own error pages. But you noticing a 403 in application logs indicates that it was indeed cause by app itself. We had noticed similar situation in a project but we were making connection to an external system and that had limits on number of parallel clients and that was translating to a 403. Anything similar in your case? Some other connection to a external service which may be getting rejected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was Apache's mod_evasive module. The problem server was configured with DoS / DDoS protection because it was available externally. mod_evasive exists to provide this exact behaviour - if Apache receives too many requests based on its configuration it returns 403 responses as a low-resource shortcut.